# Snapping stopped working properly after restarting Blender

Tags: snapping, settings

The snapping tool was working properly 8 hours ago, I reopened Blender to keep working on my project and now the snapping tool is only working with increments, regardless of the selected mode (tried it with either snapping enabled in the UI or using *CTRL* to enable it). I have changed to other options under the menu *mesh* -> *snap* but none has fixed the issue (the increments just get bigger). I don't know how to go back to default setting, nor how to understand what setting changed, nor how to debug this issue. I would really appreciate some help to fix this issue and tips on how to debug this kind of problems, as I don't see many useful info in the UI. Thank you.

[image]

Pastebin: https://pasteall.org/blend/9d3b18b893724272a90bd85341a145f7

Comment: Menu > Mesh > Snap has nothing to do with the Snapping tool. Click the dropdown beside the snapping icon in the header bar and set the option there. (Increment is the default.)

Comment: I have done this already, accessing the menu was my last attempt at fixing it. Maybe the message is not clear, but I refer to the icon you mention in the parenthesis, changing the mode there has no effect (this is how I work and indeed the first thing I tried).

Comment: Can you add an image to your question showing the current settings in the dropdown? Also what exactly are you trying to snap?

Comment: I just added it, as you can see the snapping mode is vertex, the two vertex are within the same object and the behaviour when I try  to snap either using G + CTRL or G with the snapping icon enabled is the same, the vertex moves incrementally without snapping with the other vertex

Comment: I've not seen problems like that before to be honest. Can you try starting Blender and trying it with a new scene? If that works ok, then try loading your current project without the UI by pressing 'N' in the file selector and unchecking 'Load UI' before loading. Does it work then? If you still have problems I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: That didn't work either, the worst part is that both vertices are snapped incrementally but in different abstract grids, so they can never be snapped together.

Comment: Suggest you upload the file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ so that someone else here can have a look in that case.

Comment: I just did, thank you very much for your help. I am new to Blender although I understand its basis to some extend (I studied them in my Computer Science degree). But there's something I'm still not understanding, I am creating the object just by extruding vertex and filling faces, yet some duplications appear. On top of that -and since I'm creating a cardholder- I'm only extruding towards one axis at a time, so I can't understand where this NON-PARALLEL duplications appear. Is there something basic I'm missing?

Comment: I think the issue has to do with a bad usage of the solidify modifier on my side, the extra vertices and edges pop up after applying it

Comment: Ah ok. I've just had a chance to try it and I see what you mean about the snapping. No idea why it's doing that. However, if you want to merge the vertices, selecting both and using the 'M' > Merge... route does work! Just make sure you select them in the correct order and choose the correct merge direction.